# What is recognised as the best image classification neural network for 2018?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, conv-neural-network, imagenet

Prior to 2017, it was relatively simple to understand which CNN was the best to classify images with the imagnet yearly competition.

[image]

In 2017 the imagenet competition was divided into different [tasks](http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2017/results) with winners such as [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.01507).  In 2018, the competition moved to kaggle and became about 3D detection.

I am interested in image classification only and there no longer seems to be a competition for this.

Does anyone know what neural network was recognised as the best for image classification in 2018?

Answer (score 1):

If i recall correct I think it is Googles NasNet. It's a very cool (and computer intensive) method used to design the model architecture, but good for transfer learning and prediction. I would recommend taking a look at the [NasNet-paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.07012.pdf)

It should also be available to use through `keras.application`

Answer (score 1):

This is a really good question. I was wondering about the same and played around with some of the models that are on [TensorFlow Hub](https://tfhub.dev/s?module-type=image-classification). So, here are my two cents.

The current best models in terms of performance on ImageNet are the ones which are obtained with [Progressive Neural Architecture Search](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.00559). On the other hand, these models are incredibly slow to train because they are huge. When it comes to the models such as InceptionNet, ResNet, and VGG, this is a [good link](https://github.com/jcjohnson/cnn-benchmarks) to check out the performance compared to the training/inference speed.

My personal experience is that if you want to maximize performance, use [ResNet152](https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v2_152/classification/3). If you want a relatively fast CNN, while achieving good performance, go with [ResNet50](https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v2_50/classification/3). When it comes to the VGG nets, I played around with the [TF-Slim implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/vgg.py) but it was slower than ResNet50, with performance around the same. Finally, I can't say much about Inception because I didn't use it. In the end, I went with ResNet152, because it yield the best performance for me (Please note that I was using a pre-trained version and I was fine-tuning it to my task).

To summarize, I think that there is no general **best CNN**. I would avoid using VGG16/19, because it yields worse performance than ResNet50, while being slower. If you have access to a lot of computational power, go with Resnet152 or PNASNet. Again, this my opinion based on my personal experience by playing around with the pre-trained models on TF-Hub.